# Can multiple users access ArcGIS styles on server at same time or only one?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, style, style-manager

Running ArcGIS 10.0 in our environment.

I created a styles db and saved it on the server. Can multiple users access the styles at the same time or only one?

Second, after experimenting I can add the style with the Style Manager and then click on "Set as Default List" and I think that will make it so that any new map created will reference the styles by default, or is it only for that map?

I don't quite understand how the styles are referenced. Is it per map or per ArcMap session?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer fully because I don't know all the intricacies of the personal Access MDB behaviour in a server environment. Perhaps this will help; the Style file is an mdb MS Access database so all the rules of the MS Access mdb apply, this includes locks, etc. Access is not a multi-user MDBMS so there will likely be issues with multiple users attempting to save symbols but reading symbols should be OK.

As for the second question; styles will be always assigned arbitrarily but if you create and save a simple style and name it the same as a feature class (say Lakes or Waterbodies) any feature class you will add to map whose name is Lakes or Waterbodies will inherit that particular style.  I believe this only works with a simple symbols; suppose you have sub-types defined which will not work because more than one symbol will be assigned to the layer based on subtype. Any symbology that is more complex than a single simple symbol needs to be handled via layers (save and import layer symbology).

Comment: MSAccess can be used by multiple users concurrently. I have several dbs right now on the server that are used by the 15 users in my group and more than one can be in the db at the same time. It really depends on how the db is opened. Was hoping that someone might have experience with this. On the second I think you are confusing a style file with a layer file. The style file saves symbology so that it shows up in your symbology editor. For example I can create a polyline for rivers and save it in my style file. Next time I edit a polyline feature class the rivers symbology will be a selection.

Comment: I am definitely NOT confusing style file with layer file. Data added to map automatically inherits symbology from a style file if the symbol has the same name as the feature class being added. As I've mentioned in my answer, there are exceptions.

Comment: Hmm ill give that a try. I know i have styles called "airport" and "city" and dont remember those being assigned when my feature class has the same name. Let me try it though. I may not have even noticed it.